# How can I validate data if not in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

The Microsoft code guidline forbids complex operations in a constructor ( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/constructor)

What's the proper way to validate the input data if not in the constructor. Here is an example:

```
class User{
    User(string id){
        Validate(id); //Looks up id in database or remote service
    }
}
```

The validate should not be called in the constructor. But how can I make sure I don't have a User class with an invalid id?

Comment: A database query or a remote server connection to validate a value is an expensive operation and the code guidline says the constructor should be very fast.

Comment: Validation should be done before trying to create the object. In any case, a "small" validation is not a complex operation

Comment: Then I have to make the constructor private and add a static factory method. No idea if this is a better solution

Answer (score -1):

Basically it depends on whether the operation is actually complex.

In case that the operation is complex, you can use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) and validate the values inside:

```
class User{

    private string _id;

    public int Id
    {
       get
       {
           return _id;
       }
       set
       {
           if (Validate(value))
           {
               _id = value;
           }
       }
    }

    User(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Doing database operations inside a property setter is even worse!

Comment: Then I can create an invalid (=no id) user object.